# Git push all commits as single commit with custom message

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

I was wondering if it is possible to push all my local commits (all 'unpushed' commits of the day) to the remote repository as a single commit with a custom message. None of the posts on Stack Overflow seem to answer this. I'm using Git Bash on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is called "squash". Take a look here:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/527-squash-several-git-commits-into-a-single-commit

Comment: Thanks a million just what I was looking for. I skipped the merge command though, as I'm working with master branch

Answer (score 3):

Use `git rebase -i HEAD~N` where `N` is `<the number of your commits> + 1` (to be on the safe side). You will need to mark all your commits but the first one as `s` (stands for "squash") and save/quit the editor. It will ask you for the commit message for the final squashed commit - specify one, and you are done.

Comment: `git log` will show all your commits, and `git reflog` will help you even more, showing all your pulls/rebases.